# c# Regex for getting strings and number ranges

Tags: c#, regex

I want to tell whether or not a string contains "x mins ago" or "Just Now" x being a number between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

#### n mins ago

```
/^\d+ mins ago$/
```

If you explicitly want only a number between 1 and 5...

```
/^[1-5] mins ago$/
```

#### Just Now

Just do a normal string comparison. No reason to use regex to match a constant string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^([1-5] mins ago)|(Just Now)$
```

Comment: Since he only asked for the string to contain the pattern I suggest to leave out the ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can try this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"([1-5]\s+mins\s+ago|just\s+now)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```